# how to get around safari on mobile when my webpage isn't scrollable

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, safari, mobile-safari

My webpage has a height of 100%, so it is impossible to scroll. However, when you open it on mobile safari, I run into an issue where some of my content is covered by the address bar and the bar at the bottom.

I've tried using javascript to edit my content only when the browser is Safari, with

```
var isSafari = /constructor/i.test(window.HTMLElement) || (function (p) 
{ return p.toString() === "[object SafariRemoteNotification]"; }) . 
(!window['safari'] || safari.pushNotification);

$(document).ready(function() {
if (isSafari) {
  $('#map').css('bottom', '25px');
}
});
```

but that is making the #map has a bottom: 25px no matter what browser is being used.

What is the best way to handle Safari on mobile?